# Laravel notifiable - Send Notification To Selected User

Tags: mysql, laravel, notifications

Im trying to do a notification function where the system should send notification to the selected user(carOwnerName) in dropdown list.

**carOwnerName** is a userId that will be stored in mysql after user select from dropdown list

Here's some codes

**Notification(carNotify)**

```
class carNotify extends Notification
{
    protected $validations;

    public function __construct($validations)
    {
        $this->validations = $validations;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database']; 
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'User_id' => $this->validations->carOwnerName,

        ];
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $validations = Cars::findOrFail($id);
    $validations->carOwnerDept = $request->input('carOwnerDept');
    $validations->carOwnerName = $request->input('carOwnerName');
    $input = $request->all();
    $validations->fill($input)->save();
    $user =  $validations->carOwnerName = $request->carOwnerName;
    $user->sendNotification($validations);
    Session::flash('flash_message', 'News updated successfully!');
    return Redirect::to('/validateCars')->with('success', "Successfully Validated !");
```

**Cars Model**

```
    public function sendNotification($validations)
    {
        $this->notify(new carNotify($validations));
    }
```

**Views**

```
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">

                    <a class="nav-link " data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
                        @foreach (Auth()->user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
                        @if($notification->data['cars']['carOwnerName'] == auth()->user()->id)
                        <span class="badge badge-danger">{{ Auth()->user()->unreadnotifications->count()}}</span></a>

                    @else

                    <span class="badge badge-primary">0</span></a>

                    @endif
                    @endforeach
```

This is my first time doing the laravel notification function. Any suggestion?

Comment: Just find out that the notifiable_id column trigger the notification. How to insert carOwnerName into notifiable_id column? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue **Solved** with the following codes :)

```
   User::find($validations->carOwnerName)->notify(new carNotify($validations));
```